# A fly on a triangle?

Tags: probability, puzzle, random-walk, solution-verification

A fly is on the vertex of a triangle. It can move left with probability $\frac 12$ and right with probability $\frac 12$.

What is the expected number of moves till it reaches its starting point?

This is my attempted solution.

Let $N$ be the number of moves and let $L$ denote the event the fly moves left on its first turn and $R$ denote the event that it moves right on its first turn. Then

$E[N]=E[N|L]P(L)+E[N|R]P(R)$

$E[N]=E[N|L]\frac{1}{2}+E[N|R]\frac{1}{2}$

Also

$E[N|R]=2\frac{1}{2}+E[N|L]\frac{1}{2}$

since the fly can jump back to its starting point with probability $1/2$ but if it moves right again then this is the same as if it had jumped left on its first go. Similarly

$E[N|L]=2\frac{1}{2}+E[N|R]\frac{1}{2}$

solving this sytem of equations I find $E[N|L]=E[N|R]=2$ and hence $E[N]=2$. But this does not seem right to me. Any ideas where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Why to mention "a triangle" if it doesn't appear in the development later? Perhaps the meaning of "moving left/right" is on the corresponding triangle's sides?

Comment: @DonAntonio thats what I mean

Comment: ...and the moves are between vertex and vertex, right? And the "game" ends if an when the fly reaches the original vertex...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to note that the two non-starting nodes are symmetric, so the expected number of moves to get back to start from $L$ and $R$ are the same.  As your move from start is to $L$ or $R$, $E[N]=1+E[R]$  Then $E[R]=\frac 12(1) + \frac 12E[R]$ because you have half chance to go to start and half chance to go to left (which has the same expectation as right).  So $E[R]=2, E[N]=3$

For your try, you forgot to add the $1$ move from $N$ to $L$ or $R$.  Also writing $2\frac 12$ when you mean the product is confusing.  Many (and maybe you later) will read it as $2+\frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_n$ be the number of starting moves required to get back to vertex $1$ if you are on vertex $n$ ($n=1,2,3$).  Then we have:

\begin{align}
k_1&=0\\
k_2&=1+\frac12k_1+\frac12k_3=1+\frac12k_3\\
k_3&=1+\frac12k_1+\frac12k_2=1+\frac12k_2\\
\end{align}

(Since if you are on $k_2$, say, you have to travel $1$ step, and then you land on vertex $1$ with probability $\frac12$, and vertex $3$ with probability $\frac12$, so we have a contribution of $\frac12k_1+\frac12k_3$ to the expected total number of steps.)

Solving these gives:

$$
k_2=1+\frac12k_3=1+\frac12+\frac14k_2\\
\frac34k_2=\frac32\\
k_2=2
$$

Similarly, $k_3=2$.

Now, the expected number of steps given that you start on vertex $1$ (and this does not immediately mean that you've arrived) is given by $1+\frac12k_2+\frac12k_3$, by a similar argument, and this is given by $1+1+1=3$.

Answer (score 1):

After the first step this is the "gambler's ruin" problem for gamblers with $1$ and $2$ dollars respectively (the distances back to the start in the two directions).

Comment: It was unclear if the question is about additional solutions, verification of the presented argument, or the first for the purpose of the second.  At least the above is an independent way to write down the answer.